# updating query parameters in SQL Data Source

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have following code that updates the value of query parameters of a SQL Data Source after going through some conditions.

```
SqlDataSource sdm = new SqlDataSource("<our connection string>", "SELECT  [Message Id] ,[To] ,[From] ,[Reply To] ,[Subject] ,[Message] ,[Date added] FROM [database].[dbo].[User Messages] where ([to]=@sid or [from]=@sid) and ([to]=@qid or [from]=@qid)  and [reply to]=@rid");

string user = Session["USERID"].ToString();
string to = Request["to"].ToString();
string from = Request["from"].ToString();
sdm.UpdateParameters["rid"].DefaultValue = Request["replyid"].ToString();
sdm.UpdateParameters["sid"].DefaultValue = user;
if (user == to)
  sdm.UpdateParameters["qid"].DefaultValue=from;
else
  sdm.UpdateParameters["qid"].DefaultValue= to;

sdm.Update();
sdm.DataBind();
Repeater1.DataSource = sdm;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

Its showing NullReferenceException at `sdm.UpdateParameters["rid"].DefaultValue = Request["replyid"].ToString();`

`rid` is already set in query string as `?rid=a`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the query string be `?replyid=a` instead of `?rid=a?`.

It seems that `Request["replyid"]` returns null, and then `ToString()` throws the exception.

Comment: If this is indeed the problem, the question should be closed, as simple typos are too localized to help anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `Request.QueryString` collection to get your `rid` parameter out:

```
sdm.UpdateParameters["rid"].DefaultValue = Request.QueryString["rid"];
```

Using an indexer with `Request` will get you values out of the `QueryString`, `Form`, `Cookies` or `ServerVariables` collections, using `Request.QueryString` directly makes your intentions that little bit clearer.